# URLconfs in Django

Tags: python, django

I am going through the Django sample application and come across the URLConf.

I thought the import statement on the top resolves the url location, but for 'mysite.polls.urls' I couldn't remove the quotes by including in the import statement.

Why should I use quotes for 'mysite.polls.urls' and not for admin url? and what should I do if I have to remove the quotes.

```
   from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
    ...
    ...
    (r'^polls/', include('mysite.polls.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've elided a bunch of stuff, but do you have the following statement in there?

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

If so, that would explain why you don't need to quote the latter.  See the django documentation for [AdminSite.urls](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf) for more information.

If you want to remove the quotes from the former, then:

```
import mysite.poll.urls
...
(r'^polls/', include(mysite.poll.urls)),
...
```

should work.

Comment: Thx. Worky perfectly. Could you explain how quoting works? He tries to built from the current workpath?

Comment: I haven't looked at the django source, but yes, I think it just tries to import some segment of the string, assuming it's on the PYTHONPATH.  See the imp module for one possible way to make it work: http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html